# How to improve my linked-list exercise?

Tags: java, algorithm, singly-linked-list

I am doing the exercise 1.3.26 of book "Algorithms FOURTH EDITION".

> /**
>    * 1.3.26  Write a method remove() that takes a linked list 
>    * and a string key as arguments and removes all of the nodes 
>    * in the list that have key as its item field.
>    *
>    * java LinkListRemove to
>    * to to be or to to go to to to die
>    * ^z / ^d
>    * before remove:
>    * to to be or to to go to to to die
>    * result of remove:
>    * be or go die
>    * size: 4
>    * 
>    */

My implementation is here [LinkListRemove](https://github.com/morrxy/algs4/blob/master/exercise/1.3.26/LinkListRemove.java), and it works. But I feel it's not elegant. Is it possible to use only one time traversal of the singly linked list?

My train of thought is a 2-step process:

1. Remove consecutive keys from first, after processing, the linklist begins with a non-key node or is empty.
2. Remove matched node after the first node, now the linklist begins with a non-key node or is empty.

If you want to run it, you need [this jar file](http://introcs.cs.princeton.edu/java/stdlib/stdlib.jar).

Comment: You can improve it by working hard on it rather than asking

Comment: There is no problem at all. You traverse the list exactly once.

Answer (score 0):

As much as i understand from your question, you want to remove all the elements from the list which match with the given key.

Yes, this can be done in one iteration of the list. Below steps should help :

```
Node temp =null;
if(key != null && first != null){
    if(key.equals(first.item)){               
        temp = first;
        first = first.next;
        temp.link=null;
        temp =null;
        return;
    }
    else{
        Node tempIt = first.link;
        temp = first;
        while(tempIt != null)
            {
                if(key.equals(tempIt.item)){
                    temp.link = tempLt.link;
                    tempLt.link = null;
                    tempLt = null;
                }
                temp = tempLt;
                tempLt= tempLt.next;
            }
        }
}   
return;
```